# My Kumite fight after 4 hours

Tags: karate

Today is my kumite after 4 hours
Plz give some advices to me so that i can do better. I had practised a lot for today's kumite match.give me some advices on what should we do probably before a kumite and what should we do to stay calm and fearless to face the fight and how we can understand our opponent during the fight , style is shito ryu,i am a purple belt,.i want to fight very strongly and my aim is to get many points without letting the opponent to take a single point from me..help me by giving some precious advices and thanx for giving your precious time to my question.fast

Comment: This question has many problems. First, it is too broad because you have not defined what you are not doing well. Second, doing better is highly subjective and dependent on your goals (not given), your organisation (not given), and your rank (not given). Lastly, your style of writing does not make it easy to understand what you want. I hope you edit your question to make it easier to read and clearer as I think there is a good question in there, somewhere.

Comment: Now its ok sadarthion.

Comment: Plz answer my question sardathrion

Comment: I would suggest you take the [tour](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how this site works. Your questions is still unclear and rambling.

Comment: The only answer I can give you is (the unhelpful) [git gud](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/git-gud) because that is what you need. Unless you narrow down your question and make it clearer, that is the only answer.

Comment: I am tired now i have given all the possible details that i can give i dont know what is wrong with my question.i only asked to give advices on what should we do probably before a kumite and what should we do to stay calm and fearless to face the fight

Comment: Then you have two questions: "What should we do probably before a kumite" and "What should we do to stay calm". Both are interesting questions and I urge you to ask them. One of those (say the first one), could be an edit of this one. However, since you are tired, I would suggest waiting till you rest before doing so.

Comment: Now if u know my question than answer.

Comment: Plz tell me only 1 and a half hours left

Comment: [Git gud](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/git-gud)

Comment: No one can help you in the time frame you've given.  4 hours isn't enough time to change your training or conditioning.  The only thing people could tell you would be based on how you already move & your strengths and weaknesses - which is something only your teacher, coach, or fellow students would know.  Go do your fight, get video, come back with questions on why things worked, or didn't work for you, and get advice for your next round of training.

Comment: I only asked for giving advice on  how can i be fearless and stay calm before kumite and the answer i have got from tony

Answer (score 2):

You don't have time to learn much new - and our suggestions can really only address your mental state.  I suggest you imagine ***being*** the fighter you feel you need to be to dominate the fight.  Imagine the determination you'd need, feel it, "own it" so to speak.  Work out one or two things you think you can use to win - speed, suddenness of movement, power, combinations, footwork, timing - whatever you're good at, or perhaps you'll see the opponent has a related weakness.  Go into the fight with the mindset that you're already a blackbelt, you can trust in your techniques - they're just tools you can use as easily as snapping your fingers, and seize the right times to use them.  Stay determined but open-minded and analytical so when things don't go your way you work past the problems quickly and find a way to use your strengths.  When something works, keep using it or variations on it, or use the threat of it as a set-up for something else completely, to get the most "value" possible out of it and keep the opponent unsettled.  If you find yourself in trouble, be quick about working out how to change things up so avoid it - for example, if you're trying to defend but getting hit anyway, forget about it and start attacking.  Good luck!

Comment: This was the answer that i needed and thank u very i wuold remember your advice in my whole life thanx tony.my karate sensei has chosen me for  a tournament by seeing my skills

Comment: Tony can u tell me how can i understand my opponent

Comment: @user26453 You're welcome.  Understanding your opponent is a huge question - too big to really answer in comments.  Still, a few thoughts: it requires experience, observation and careful analysis.  Long term, just do your best against lots of different opponents - you should naturally improve.  You have to fight "better" opponents sometimes and learn as much as you can each time, but even fighting people you can already dominate - vary your fighting style so you learn more, or set yourself challenges like keeping them off-balance with low kicks, or getting elbow strikes through their guard.

Comment: During kumite - think about what they're expecting and comfortable with... Do they wait for you to attack or charge forwards? Do they attack once or in a short flurry then retreat, or stay in close for a while?  Do they focus on punching and forget to kick, or vice versa?  Do they try to block everything well, or are they trying to do the minimum - even wearing a few hits - while focused on getting a big counter-attack in?  Do they try to keep you at a distance?  Try to force them into a type, pace/tempo, range of fighting they're not used to, comfortable with or good at.

Comment: Tony what would i do if my opponent waits for me to attack.will i go to attack him?

Comment: @user26453 It depends - he might be doing that because he's nervous, in which case you probably should attack, but might want to feint a bit first to see if he overreacts and leaves himself more vulnerable; or he might be really good defending or counter-attacking, in which case take your time, see if he gets impatient.  If you've a reach advantage, try patiently to get some hits in from the edge of his range - after you've "scored" he'll then have to try to go on the offensive to even up the fight, and you'll have him fighting in a way he's less comfortable with.

Comment: what do you mean by that if the opponent overreacts and leaves himself more vulnerable and what do u mean by that try patiently to get some hits in from the edge of his range

Comment: Tony plz answer my question

Comment: @user26453 re "opponent overreacts" - say you've been able to get punches through to your opponent's head a couple times - the opponent may be very wary and keeping their guard high, so you could feint (i.e. fake) another punch to the head, but instead watching to see if and where they leave themselves vulnerable (e.g. perhaps to a kick, or a punch delivered a moment later).

Comment: re "patiently get hits in from the edge of his range" - if you're taller and your opponent's waiting for you to attack aggressively, hoping to counter-attacker, but not wanting to have to close the gap (i.e. they want you coming towards and attacking them without having to themselves initiate getting close enough to hit you), then you have a huge advantage - you can occupy the distance at the edge of your own range - where you can hit them, but they can't hit you.  Just by moving around at that distance, feinting, throwing some exploratory attacks, you can pick your time to really attack.

Comment: You can read more about fighting shorter opponents [here](http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/5805/1618).  Contrasting with that, if you're the shorter fighter, you should generally be initiating action to get and stay close enough to hit.

Comment: More generally, there are a huge number of factors and strategies in kumite - way too many to list in an answer on this forum.  You have to accept that experience, careful thought, a good instructor and school will eventually give you lots of insights, and with hard work you'll build up and be able to apply this kind of knowledge.